# REGEX Help, variable name after an = sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text block

```
[QUOTE=Name;123]Text[/QUOTE]
```

I am trying to build a regex to identify the section "Name" and "Text" and pull those variables out.

This is all going into a javascript str.replace function, but having a hell of a time getting it to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below replacement will do:

```
var string = "[QUOTE=Name;123]Text[/QUOTE]";
var search = /\[QUOTE=(.*?);\d+\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/QUOTE\]/i;
var replacement = "Quoted by $1: $2";
var result = string.replace(re, replacement);
// result becomes "Quoted by Name: Text"
```

- it's case-insensitive, `[quote=user;1]text[/quote]` is matched as well as `[QUOTE=user;1]text[/QUOTE]`
- it matches `;` followed by digits, but ignores it.
- It does match over multiple lines. `.` does not match newlines, so I used `[\s\S]` to match all characters.
- The "user" and "text" are matched by any character (even empty ones). If you know that "user" consists of letters, digits and spaces only, replace `.*?` by `[a-z0-9 ]*`. If you know that a user name length is between 3 and 20, you can use: `[a-z0-9 ]{3,20}`

This RE is really simple and does not work with nested quotes. Like HTML parsing using regular expressions, it's impossible to build a single RE that converts BB code properly. Use a real BB code parser that searches for opening tags and closing tags so you can close your tags properly.

Comment: Works great except it picks up the ;123 after the name, anyway to exclude the semicolon and the number?

Answer (score 2):

```
"[QUOTE=Name;123]Text[/QUOTE]".match(/\[QUOTE=(.*);.*\](.*)\[\/QUOTE\]/)
```

results in:

```
["[QUOTE=Name;123]Text[/QUOTE]", "Name", "Text"]
```

Basically you replace the variables with `(.*)` to parse them out, and you need to escape special characters.

When removing them you can do:

```
"[QUOTE=Name;123]Text[/QUOTE]".replace(/\[QUOTE=.*;.*\].*\[\/QUOTE\]/, "[QUOTE=;123][/QUOTE]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming name, text are alphanumeric):

```
\[QUOTE=(\w+);123\](\w+)\[/QUOTE\]

var re = /\[QUOTE=(\w+);123\](\w+)\[\/QUOTE\]/;
var str = "[QUOTE=Name;123]Text[/QUOTE]";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$1 - $2");  // $2 is text, $1 is name
```

Edit your replacement string as per your requirement.